# Big Oh and Taylor polynomials.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Prove the following statement.

> Suppose $f$ has $n+1$ continuously differentiable derivatives on $[a,b]$, let $c \in (a,b)$.
>   We define $P_n(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{f^{k} (c)  w^k}{k!}$. Then $f(x) - P_n(x) = O(w^{n+1}) $ at $0$.

Comment: What's the theorem? What are we trying to prove?

Comment: The first grey box is the theorem

Comment: @sidht I think your formulas are all mixed up. You have your derivatives evaluated at $c$, but your polynomial is centered at $0$.

Comment: You have $M$ and $m$ which are used but not defined, and you have $V$ and $v$ which are defined but not used. Can you look to make sure everything is written properly?

Comment: Okay it should be fine now.

Comment: Just a side remark that the assumption that $f$ be $(n+1)$-times differentiable is necessary, as the example $f(x) = |x|^{n+1/2}$ shows.

Comment: Huh, didn't the problem state that? So from your comment, I assume I did good?

Comment: @sidht I think you mean $x \in [a,b]$, not $w\in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Proof**
>
> By Taylor's theorem, we have $$| f(x) - P_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!}M|w^{n+1}|$$ where $M = max\{ |f^{n+1}(w)| : w \in [a,b]\}$.  So we are done.